# How to set Morris Chart y axis resolution

Tags: exchangewebservices, morris.js

I would like to display exchange rates via morris.js Chart.
How can i change or set the resolution/precision of y-axis, i have to do this because now i can't see the rate change of any currency.I only see a horizontal line.

```
Example : EUR->USD timestamp1 1.321
                   timestamp2 1.341
                   timestamp3 1.301
```

Difference is very small between rates, because of it i can see only a horizontal line.

```
 function drawChart()
 {  
    $('#chart_container').empty();
      new Morris.Line({
          element: 'chart_container',
          data: data,
          xkey: 'time',
          ykeys: ['rate'],
          gridIntegers: true,
          labels: ['Value'],
          ymin: 0,
          yLabelMargin: 10
        });
 }
```

I attached a picture.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to change ymin values: `ymin : 400 & ymax : 5001`